# Display only selected brand in fronted for new customer registration page magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

[image]
I created custom attributes Brand with multi select option and I display Brand on registration page but I want If customer select only one brand then they can see only that brand in fronted instead of all.
Can you help me?

Comment: @kriran assume you have `customer_brand` as your customer attribute which saved when customer select from registration.

On FE when you have $customer model you could get it by `$customer->getData('customer_brand')`

Comment: Hi Tuyen, Can you explain in detail?